# npm - same dependency version getting different dependencies tree

Tags: npm, ember.js

In my two projects, I have defined devDependencies for optional-features as

`"@ember/optional-features": "^1.3.0",`

But when I do `npm ls` after `npm install` in both projects, I get different dependency tree.

One has

```
├─┬ @ember/optional-features@1.3.0
│ └─┬ inquirer@7.1.0
│   └── lodash@4.17.15  deduped
```

Second one has :

```
├─┬ @ember/optional-features@1.3.0
│ └─┬ inquirer@7.3.3
│   └── lodash@4.17.21  deduped
```

In [ember/option-features](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-optional-features/blob/v1.3.0/package.json#L30), inquirer is defined as `"inquirer": "^7.0.1",`

I have verified that I am using same nvm version for both the projects.

Why **npm** is not getting same **inquirer@7.3.3** for both projects? Is there something I am missing?

Note: Tried updating the package using

- npm update --save-dev @ember/optional-features@1.3.0
- npm intsall --save-dev @ember/optional-features@1.3.0

But still it has the same dependency tree.

Comment: you run `npm update @ember/optional-features` to bump its dependencies. The lockfile for each project was created at different times when different versions were available for each dep.

Comment: It is not working. Tried with --depth 10 too.

Comment: the next best option is probably to open your lockfile and delete all the entires for @ember/optional-features, inquirer, and lodash -- and then when you run npm-install, you should get the latest of each, assupming inquirer is using ^ on the lodash dep